# Display Value of a nodes RGB input in a panel

Tags: python, node-editor

I have a Mix RGB node and want to display the input in a normal panel in the UI.
I can show the color widget by using `layout.prop(input,"default_value")`, but what I want to do is to just show the Value of the input. This would then show a float input instead of the color widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the indexed element, eg red is index 0**

[image]

For array properties can display an individual element in a `layout.prop(...)` by specifying the index of the array element.  Eg for the red channel of mix color input `input.default_value`

```
layout.prop(input, "default_value", index=0)
```

The color node socket input has a type `'RGBA'`

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    # node for testing
    node = bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"]
    input = node.inputs["Color1"]
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    for i, c in enumerate(input.type): 
        col.prop(
                input, "default_value", 
                text=c.upper(),
                index=i)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a [`label`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=label#bpy.types.UILayout.label)?
I haven't tested the following, but something like this:

```
value_string = "({:.1f}, {:.1f}, {:.1f})".format(
                                    input.default_value[0],
                                    input.default_value[1],
                                    input.default_value[2])

layout.label(text=value_string)
```

Comment: This just displays the different values. What I want, is to display the Value as in HueSaturationValue as a layout.prop(...)

Comment: There may be a better way, but what about creating three new float properties and having some python set the node color when they are changed?

Comment: Yeah I guess that'd be possible, I hoped there was a better way, but maybe I just have to do that.