# How to get a single input property of a node to draw in the UI panel directly in the panel?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I saw [this example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139539/display-value-of-a-nodes-rgb-input-in-a-panel), but I'm not going to draw the whole XYZ (In my case), I just want to take the input properties individually, but I don't understand how

```
nodes = context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes
map = nodes.get('Mapping')
if map:
    layout.prop(map.inputs[1],'default_value[0]',text='Position X')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`UILayout.prop` index argument**

Use the index property for single array elements.

```
layout.prop(map.inputs[1], "default_value", text="Position X", index=0)
```

Would point out that this is used in my answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139620/15543 to link posted in your question?

FWIW. For pep8 formatting put a space after a comma in arguments list.

It is recommended in blender to use double quotes for strings, and single quotes for enums.

Comment: I think this question is to be considered a duplicate, for my oversight I had not noticed that you had put index inside, I did not know about this practice, but now I know.
It was exactly what I was looking for